# Angular 7 - await subscribe result in for/of loop

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and using the decision tree I'm still not sure which rxjs operator to use for my situation. It's an old app that I inherited and have to tip toe around existing services.

After I upload some images, process them in a loop and as you might expect, all the `collectionService.processImage` Observable results pile up like a car crash.

```
onUploaded($event): void {
  for(const item of $event) { // ----------------- outer loop
    for (const r of this.collection.rows) { // --- inner loop
      if (r.rowid === item.rowId) {
        r[this.imageColProp] = item.key;
        this.collectionsService
          .processImage(this.collection.listid, item.rowId, item.key)
          .subscribe(
            (result) => {
              ...
              // use result and continue outer loop
              ...
            },
            (err) => {
              this.toastr.error(err);
            }
          );
      }
    };
  };
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
public async onUploaded($event) {
  for(const item of $event) { // ----------------- outer loop
    for (const r of this.collection.rows) { // --- inner loop
      if (r.rowid === item.rowId) {
        r[this.imageColProp] = item.key;
        await this.collectionsService
          .processImage(this.collection.listid, item.rowId, item.key)
          .subscribe(
            (result) => {
              ...
              // do synchronous stuff with result then continue outer loop
              ...
            },
            (err) => {
              this.toastr.error(err);
            }
          );
      }
    };
  };
}
```

This gives me `Uncaught (in promise): ProgressEvent: {"isTrusted":true}`;

```
public async onUploaded($event) {
  for(const item of $event) { // ----------------- outer loop
    for (const r of this.collection.rows) { // --- inner loop
      if (r.rowid === item.rowId) {
        r[this.imageColProp] = item.key;
        const result = await this.collectionsService
          .processImage(this.collection.listid, item.rowId, item.key).toPromise();
          // do synchronous stuff with result

      }
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: Which version of rxjs you are using?. First thing to say you can't achieve what you what with `Array.forEach` method it just executes the callback on every item and there is no chance to await the previous callback. You need an actual foreach for this. And you need to convert your observable into a `Promise` and then await that promise in the loop.

Comment: How is your this.collection.rows consumed?

Comment: @Eldar I updated my op with the `toPromise()` version and I get an uncaught in Promise error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at `concat`. See [Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat).
In order to use `concat` you need to change your implementation to create an array of observables to use as argument.

```
    public onUploaded($events: Array<{ rowid: string, key: string }>): void {
        const imageProcesses = $events.reduce((state, item) => {
            return [
                ...state,
                ...this.collection.rows
                    .filter((r) => r.rowid === item.rowid)
                    .map((r) => {
                        r[this.imageColProp] = item.key;

                        return this.collectionsService.processImage(this.collection.listid, item.rowid, item.key);
                    }),
            ]
        }, []);

        concat(...imageProcesses).subscribe((result) => { /* success */ }, (err) => { /* error */ });
    }
```

Comment: forgive the noobiness, but I'm not sure how to nail the syntax, specifically where to put `this.collectionsService.processImage(this.collection.listid, item.rowId, item.key)`

Comment: Basically you need  to create an array of observables (in your case the `.processImage` function calls).

I tried to migrate your code to `concat` but I can't guarantee that it's correct. (see original answer)

Comment: thank you so much. I'm so close. Your logic works, but when I log `result` it returns an Observables for each file, but there doesn't seem to be any accessible data in it... just operator, source, _isScalar & [[Prototype]], etc. -- is that correct?

Comment: Ah, i think  i made a mistake in the example code: it has to be `concat(...imageProcesses)`

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use `forkJoin` for this:
first create an array of observables:

```
const arr=[];
for (const item of this.collection.rows) {
   arr.push(this.collectionsService.processImage(this.collection.listid, item.rowId, item.key));
}
forkJoin(arr).subscribe(() => {
   // do synchronous stuff with result then continue outer loop
});
```

I used your code for sample to show you the concept. so u need to change it.
also note that forJoin preserve the orders.